# Can't get OneDrive authorization code from GET request

Tags: python, get, onedrive

I have problems with retreiving auth code from URL from OneDrive.
Code I use:

```
url = 'https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf'
payload = {'client_id': client_id,
           'scope': scope,
           'response_type': response_type,
           'redirect_uri': redirect_uri}
r = requests.get(url, params=payload)
```

How can I get the code which comes with the redirection to the my page? `r.text` for instance gives me the html code of the Outlook html page. Here is the result: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18661124/python_onedrive.txt

Comment: The problem is I just don't get to the url, where the code is. It just stays on that Outlook url, and `r.history` doesn't return anything

Comment: Can you provide more details about where you are calling from? Is this a webpage, desktop app or mobile app? The auth flow varies depending on which experience you are building for.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I try to call OneDrive API from the desktop application.

Comment: Is the redirect URL you are using the "desktop" redirect URL?

Comment: @RGregg, URL looks like this:
https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=0000000000000000&scope=wl.signin%20wl.basic&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://vmelnyk.net/1drv/landingpage.php'

Comment: If you're doing OAuth from a desktop application, your redirect URL should be https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf and you need to enable "Mobile or Desktop client app" in your App Configuration at https://account.live.com/developers/applications/. Then you'll be able to access the authentication key.

Comment: @vadimmelnyk I have done as you said and the code is getting send on the url you stated in your comment. how to get access token from oauth20_desktop.srf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting my comment from before as the answer, for others to reference:

If you're doing OAuth from a desktop application, the redirect URL should be https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf and you need to enable "Mobile or Desktop client app" in your App Configuration at account.live.com/developers/applications. If you have it configured this way, you'll be able to access the authentication key from your app.

Comment: Putting redirect URL as desktop helped me, thank you